# querying on inverted file index

Tags: search-engine, querying, inverted-index

I have a project in school which I need to create a search engine using inverted index and I'm a bit blocked with how to continue.

I stored all the word that were in my docs (4 docs) using inverted file index, but in a way each word in a specific file has a row, so lets say the word 'like' can appears in doc 2 three times and doc 4 twice- so it will have 2 rows, word:like docid:2 hit:3 instoplist:0 and word:like docid:4 hit:2 instopelist:0 (hit is the number of time the word appeared inside the doc and instoplist if it part of the words that is in stop-list).

now I need to be able to do querying on that index.
lets say I need to find - car and (motorcycle or bicycle)
which is the best way to do that? how do I write the order of the search? how do I know to take motorcycle and bicycle first and do 'or' between them and then do 'and' with car ?

*ps- using php to write the code

I will appreciate any kind of help,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use intersection of documents containing car with ( union of documents containing motorcycle or bicycle)

Car : doc1 , doc2 , doc3

motorcycle : doc1 , doc4

bicycle: doc1, doc2

So your final list of document should be doc1, doc2

For finding intersection and union in php. 
Lets say you have 3 array $car , $motorcycle and $bicycle  containing document having these words

```
<?php

  $car = ['doc1','doc2','doc3'];

  $motorcycle = ['doc1','doc4'];

  $bicycle = ['doc1','doc2'];

  $intersect = array_merge($motorcycle, $bicycle);
  $result = array_intersect($car , $intersect);


  for($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++) {
      echo $result[$x];
      echo "<br>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: my question was more of how do I now which statement I need to take of first and what is the operation between them

Comment: First you have to find the union of motorcycle and bicycle. Then, you need to find the intersection.

Comment: here yes.. but in a different statement not necessarily... so my question is how do I know?

Comment: as your question said car and (motorcycle or bicycle) - so first solve  all the brackets and then the rest. If the brackets are not defined beforehand , you may need to define the precedence like **and** has higher precedence than **or**  OR  vice versa depending upon which suits your usecase.